# Need to write custom validator for multiple fields

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-validate

I'm a ZF newbie and would appreciate your help with writing a custom validator.

My form contains several fields that first need to be validated together. The form is a scholarship application that contains several rows of fields, each row representing a particular school grade. For each grade, the applicant has to enter grades, rank, school name, etc. They are required to enter this information for at least one grade level.

So when validating, I first need to check they have completed at least one grade row and then check the individual items within it. Validating individual fields is easy, but how do I check they have completed at least one grade row?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to override isValid() method in your Zend_Form class:

```
public function isValid($data)
{
    $valid = parent::isValid($data);

    if(!$yourCondition)
    {
        // set return variable to false
        $valid = false;
        // add some custom error message to form
        $this->addError('Some fields are incorrect!');
    }

    return $valid;
}
```